# Error : ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle

Can someone find the bug on the mentioned code please :

```
INSERT INTO FMS_LOG (FL_ID,FL_USER_ID, FL_OFFICE_ID, FL_DATETIME,
                     FL_IP,FL_FISCAL_YEAR,FL_USER_NAME,FL_USER_ADDRESS) 
VALUES 
( 105, 18, 18, 
  TO_DATE('03/Jan/2013 15:51:33PM','DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SSAM'), 
 '127.0.0.1',
 '2069/70', 
 'dordhankuta', 
 'balaju' );
```

FL_DATETIME has field type **DATE**

This is throwing error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Server side code:

```
    $this->db->query("
    INSERT INTO FMS_LOG (FL_ID,FL_USER_ID, FL_OFFICE_ID, FL_DATETIME, FL_IP,FL_FISCAL_YEAR,FL_USER_NAME,FL_USER_ADDRESS) 
    VALUES 
        (
        $next_id,
        $userinfo[user_id], 
        $userinfo[user_office_id],
        TO_DATE('".date('d/M/Y H:i:sA', time()+20700)."','DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SSAM'),
        '$client_ip',
        '$fiscal_year',
        '$userinfo[user_full_name]',
        '$address'
        )        
    ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 15PM does not exist. 
Second, years mask should be `yyyy`, not `yy`

this works:

```
select  TO_DATE('03/Jan/2013 15:51:33','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

If you want to use AM/PM be sure the hour is between 1 and 12 and this would work:

```
select  TO_DATE('03/Jan/2013 5:51:33PM','DD/MON/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM') from dual;
```